# LINQ query NOT IN

Tags: linq

I have this simple SQL query using `NOT IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM List l WHERE L.ListName NOT IN ('POType','MailClass')
```

How can I write this using LINQ query syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] listNames = {"POType", "MailClass"};
var query = from l in List
            where ! listNames.Contains(l.ListName)
            select l;
```